# Error when try to build the VFSTransport Listener class

Tags: wso2, vfs, apache-synapse

I try to modified the VFSTransportListener class in WSO2. But I encountered this error :

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Cannot override the final method from AbstractTransportListenerEx<PollTableEntry>
- overrides org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListenerEx<org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.PollTableEntry>.init
```

This error happen in the init method. 
Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Isuru Perera I use Java 1.7.. do I need to use Maven to modify this class?

Comment: @IsuruPerera Hi, I build the class using IDE. Is that a problem? :)

Comment: Using IDE is fine. I actually didn't read the error properly earlier. Looks like it's just a compile error as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to override the following method in AbstractTransportListenerEx class

```
@Override
public final void init(ConfigurationContext cfgCtx,
        TransportInDescription transportIn) throws AxisFault {

    super.init(cfgCtx, transportIn);

    doInit();

    // Create endpoint configured at transport level (if available)
    E endpoint = createEndpoint();
    endpoint.init(this, null);
    if (endpoint.loadConfiguration(transportIn)) {
        globalEndpoint = endpoint;
    }
}
```

This cannot be overridden as it is a final method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the error already exist even if I change nothing from the original code.